# How Can I use '&' character in XML code?

Tags: xml

I want to use & character but the Visual Studio throw exception. How Have to write this?

Answer (score 48):

Replace any `&` with

```
&amp;
```

It would load properly in XML.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `&amp;`  or `&#38;`, or you can wrap it in a `CDATA` section like this:

```
<![CDATA[Foo & Bar]]>
```

Answer (score 12):

There are two ways to represent characters which have special meaning in XML (such as `<` and `>`) in an XML document.

1. CDATA sections
2. As entities

A CDATA section can only be used in places where you could have a text node.

```
<foo><![CDATA[Here is some data including < and > (and &!) ]]></foo>
```

The caveat is that you can't include the sequence `]]>` as data in a CDATA section.

Entities can be used everywhere (except inside CDATA sections) and consist of `&`, then an identifier, then `;`.

```
<foo>Here is some data including &lt; and &gt; (and &amp;!)</foo>
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the entity, `&amp;`.

(+1 to the other answers that discuss CDATA.)

Answer (score 4):

You may use a `CDATA` : 
Everything inside a `CDATA` section is ignored by the parser.

A CDATA section starts with `<![CDATA[` and ends with `]]>`