# Why can't I using '&' in android resource strings.xml file in android studio?

Tags: xml

As shown in the title,I define a String using '&' in strings.xml file,but the android studio show a error?
strings.xml

```
<string name="url">
    url?locale=zh&articleNo=
</string>
```

Problems can be redefined:

We can't using special characters which have special meaning in XML.

The question is the XML syntax problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `&amp;` instead of just `&`

**UPD:** 
 Answer to "Why can't you use &" is: it is by design: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT
>   appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters,
>   or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If
>   they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped using either numeric
>   character references or the strings " & " and " < "
>   respectively. The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the
>   string " > ", and MUST, for compatibility, be escaped using either
>   " > " or a character reference when it appears in the string " ]]>
>   " in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA
>   section.

Comment: Yes,it's work.But why?

Comment: It's a problem of The XML syntax.[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823813/how-can-i-use-character-in-xml-code) is a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

For special character I normally use the Unicode definition, for the '&' for example: \u0026 if I am correct. Here is a nice reference page: http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php?block=0